# How many digits does a number have? $\lfloor \log_{2} n \rfloor +1$

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1) we have seen that there are exactly $\lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor +1$ digits in a decimal number $n$.
There is also mentioned that $n$ has $\lfloor \log_{2} n \rfloor +1$.  Is it true? If yes how can I prove it?

Comment: "*There is also mentioned that $n$ has $\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor + 1$*".... digits **in the base two** representation (*this missing phrase is incredibly important!*).  The proof is exactly the same as the decimal case, which you link to already except by replacing $10$'s with $2$'s

Comment: Technically, digits implies base $10$, you should replace digits by bits to get base $2$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr and what would you call them in a ternary system?  A quaternary system?  Digits?  Bits?  Some other phrase?  I have always called them digits in these alternate bases such as base 3, 4, etc... I see little reason to make such a strong distinction between base 2 and every other base.

Comment: @JMoravitz according to you  $2^{d-1}\le n<2^d\implies d=\lfloor\log_{2}n\rfloor+1$ right?  but for $n=8, 2^{d-1}\le n<2^d$ is not true, since here $d=1$

Comment: Primo, $8$ in binary is $1000_2$, so no, $d=4$.  Again, the base two logarithm is used to count how many digits in base 2 there are.  The base ten logarithm is used to count how many digits in base ten there are.  They are used for different things.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335055/what-is-the-relationship-between-base-and-number-of-digits

Comment: In any base b the number $b^k$ is represented as 1000.... (with k 0's) and $b^{k+1} $ as 1 with k+1 0.  So the k+1 digit numbers are precisely all x:$b^k \le x <b^k $ and $k+1 =\log_b x +1$.  Not much more to prove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof: How many digits does a number have? $\lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor +1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1)

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is an $n-$digit number in base B, then

\begin{array}{c}
   B^{n-1} \le x \lt B^n \\
   n-1 \le \log_Bx < n \\
   n-1 \le \left\lfloor \log_Bx \right \rfloor < n \\
   n \le \left\lfloor \log_Bx \right \rfloor + 1  < n+1 \\
\end{array}

It follows that the number of digits in a base-$B$ number is $\left\lfloor \log_Bx \right \rfloor + 1$.